# SAS tagsets.excelxp conditional formatting

Tags: excel, sas

I'm using tagsets.excelxp and proc report to generate a report that is dumping out to Excel.  I'm trying to get the minimum value in a column and the maximum value in a column to be highlighted red and green respectively in my output.

For example:

```
OBS   Rate    
1     5%    
2     10%    
3     15%
```

In my Excel output I'd like the 5% to be highlighted red and the 15% to be highlighted green.

I'm trying to use a compute block inside of a proc report but just can't get it to work.

Comment: excel conditional formatting

Comment: Well, I'd like to do it in the proc report in SAS and just have the report be finished when I open it in Excel.

Comment: Show your code, with a sample dataset, please.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example how to resolve that. 
You have to create macro variables before `proc report`, which store information about min and max values. 
After that you need to use `compute` block and `call define` for dynamic formating.

```
ods tagsets.ExcelXP file="C:\temp\res.xml";

proc sql noprint;
    select max(age), min(age)
    into :max, :min
    from sashelp.class;
quit;

proc report data=sashelp.class;
    column Name Age;
    compute Age;
        if Age.sum = &max. then
            call define(_row_, 'style', 'style={background=red}');
        else if Age.sum = &min. then
            call define(_row_, 'style', 'style={background=green}');
    endcomp;
run;

ods tagsets.ExcelXP close;
```